# Silex Produces 405 Errors on Form Submits

Tags: php, html, symfony, silex

I'm trying to make a form on a site using Silex, but when I POST the data, it gives me a 405 error. I'm not using the Silex form generator. Just HTML. Is there a setting in Silex that would prevent POSTing data? GET works fine.

HTML:

```
<form name='login' action='' method='POST'>
    Username: <input type='text' name='user' value=''><br />
    Password: <input type='password' name='pass' value=''><br />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you defined a route for POST?

Comment: Do you mean in Silex? I'm not sure how to do that. 

I left the action blank so it should POST to the same page and I can handle it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP's 405 status code means *method not allowed*, in your case it means you have defined a route for that url, but it doesn't accept post request. This is how it probably looks like:

```
$app->get("/myform", function () use ($app) {});
```

Even if the url itself matches, this won't match for anything but GET, everything else will result in a 405. You have two choices:

1. create a POST controller with `$app->post()`
2. create a controller that accepts both with `$app->match()`

if you go down the second path, I recommend the following pattern:

```
$app->match("/myform", function (Request) use ($app) {
    if ($request->isMethod("post")) {
        // process post data
    }
});
```

Comment: If I change it from $app->get to $app->match I get a 500 Internal Server error whether I submit data or not.

Comment: Please enable debugging mode (`$app["debug"]=true`) so you get an error message telling what's the problem.